# Use of "here document" in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, nohup

I need to wrap some code in the here document and run it with the ssh:

```
for service in ${services[@]}
do
ssh -tt root@${server} service=${service} 'bash -s' << 'ENDSSH'
    ps axf | grep "service-${service}" | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh
    nohup java -jar service-${service}.jar >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
ENDSSH
done
```

However the for loop can just do the first run and the ssh seems to catch the stdin and the `for` loop hangs there forever. How should I do to let the ssh return immediatly and continue the next for execution?

Comment: You are quoting the heredoc delimiter to prevent `awk`'s `$1` from expanding, but that also prevents `$service` from expanding.

Comment: The `$service` here was exported by the `ssh`'s env variable and the command between heredoc delimiter works properly the first loop and the corresponding service can be killed and started. The only problem here is that the `ssh` will eat the `stdin` and the loop hang there forever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can replace this:

```
ps axf | grep "service-${service}" | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh
```

With this:

```
pkill -f "service-${service}"
```

You can skip the "here document" and simplify:

```
for service in ${services[@]}
do
{
    echo "pkill -f service-${service}";
    echo "nohup java -jar service-${service}.jar >> nohup.out 2>&1 &";
} | ssh -tt root@${server}
done
```

Or if you prefer the heredoc:

```
for service in ${services[@]}
do
ssh -tt root@${server} <<EOF
    pkill -f service-${service}
    nohup java -jar service-${service}.jar >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
EOF
done
```

Comment: When I use the heredoc version the command in heredoc never run!

Comment: What if you use the non-heredoc version?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Today I tried the non-heredoc version then the for loop can only run the first loop and the ssh eat the stdin. I can just get the first service runing!

Comment: Do you really need the `-tt` option to ssh?  What happens without it?

Comment: After I removing the `-tt` option  my local terminal complains `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` But the `ssh` now won't hangs and the commands can run smoothly.

Comment: To fix that complaint, try `-T`.